# How to make a google script remove all content in a doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I sometimes need to temporarily write something in somewhere. I make a 'Temp' google doc, every times I use it I need to remove the content previously there. I want to make a google apps script to add a button to remove all content and format in doc. I try the following code:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Clear")
    .addItem("Clear", "dialogs")
    .addToUi();
}

function dialogs() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
    "Please Confirm",
    "Are you sure you want to clear the document?",
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().clear()}
}
```

However it doesn't work. How to fix that?

Comment: If you are adding the content to the document body use [Body.clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#clear()). If you need further help, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs, show what  you have tried, and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I try it but it said 'Exception: could not remove the last paragraph of the document'. I try a few other ways but they never work. Edit: Now I know why, the problem solve when I add a blank line at the end of the document. Thank you!

Comment: I just reopened the question... I suggest you to post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

When using `.getBody().clear()`, you need to make sure the last line of the document is not in bullet points or other special formats. Add a blank line in the last paragraph, and the code should work.